# Scala: Iterate over 20k images once, crop 100 ways to make 100 Iterators

Tags: image, scala, memory, split, iterator

#### requirement

I need to iterate over images, splitting each into 100 blocks (ROIs) and calculating something independently per block. I can't store anything other than the file paths in a list in memory, and I can't perform disk IO more than once. Performance is more important than simplicity here. How do I build 100 iterators while iterating over images?

#### code

I've written this a few ways but always get a StackOverflowError after ~5 hours (should finish in under 20 minutes).
The following is the way that made the most sense to me: Iterate over an in-memory list of paths and build a map of iterators.

```
def calcAll(run: ImageBase, rois: Traversable[Roi]): Map[Roi, TraversableOnce[T]] = {
    val results: mutable.Map[Roi, Iterator[T]] = emptyMutableMap(rois)

    // calculate feature between every two frames
    var prevImage: RichImage = null // it'll be ok, I promise
    for (frame <- ImageStore.walk(run) { // iterates over nio Path objects
        val image = RichImages.of(frame)
        if (prevImage != null) for (roi <- rois) {
            val next: Iterator[T] = calc(Iterator(prevImage.crop(roi), image.crop(roi)))
            results(roi) = results(roi) ++ next // StackOverflowError!!
        }
        prevImage = image
    }

    results.toMap // immutable
}
```

#### background

I have a directory of 20k grayscale frames from a video. The video has a set of 100 Regions of Interest (ROIs), non-overlapping rectangles that we care about. I need to calculate features between consecutive images, but independently for each ROI. The amount of data and number of ROIs prohibits reading an image more than once.

Comment: To clarify: I do understand why I get a stack overflow (at least I think I do), but I don't know how to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need something similar to this:

```
def calcAll(run: ImageBase, rois: Seq[Roi]): Traversable[Map[Roi, T]] = {
  ImageStore.walk(run).map(RichImages.of).sliding(2).map {
    case Seq(image1, image2) =>
      rois.map(roi => roi -> calc(image1.crop(roi), image2.crop(roi)).toMap
  }
}
```

Given that `ImageStore.walk` returns an `Iterator` or `Traversable`, this code will load each image only once and won't have to store more than two images in memory at a time.

This gives you a single iterator though. Having 100 iterators will require either storing all images in memory, or traversing them 100 times. So, unfortunately, I believe you'd have to do with a `Traversable[Map[Roi, T]]`.

Comment: Technically, ImageStore.walk actually is an in-memory list of paths.
But I see your point! There's no way to prevent the Iterators from being pulled/threaded through *independently* by the calling code. I guess I'll just need to give the code more memory so that it can store the full feature arrays. Thanks!

Comment: @DouglasMyers-Turnbull Well, you can turn it into an Iterator: `ImageStore.walk(run).toIterator.map(RichImages.of)...` This will also get you `Iterator[Map[Roi, T]]`, that traverses once & stores 2 images in memory.

Comment: @DouglasMyers-Turnbull Actually, if memory allows you to store all 2'000'000 results, you can just take my code and convert it `toList` to traverse images once, and then transpose the list in memory to get `Map[Roi, List[T]]`; or even modify your own code to build `Map[Roi, List[T]]`. It's just that making `Map[Roi, Iterator[T]]` doesn't work very well.